# Prevent HTML / Markdown from getting indexed in Elasticsearch with Searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm currently doing this to prevent HTML tags from getting indexed by Searchkick:

```
# model.rb
def clean_teaser
  ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(teaser)
end

# Searchkick index
def search_data
  {
    title: title,
    teaser: clean_up_teaser
  }
end
```

but I'm wondering if I should be relying on Elasticsearch's [html_strip](https://gist.github.com/clintongormley/780895) setting to do this, and if so, how to accomplish that with [Searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) without switching to Elasticsearch DSL. It may simply not be supported at this point, so alternatives are welcome. Then again this currently works without any performance issues so maybe I should just stick with it. Thoughts?

Comment: I have the same problem, any luck so far?

Comment: @Jacka I've been using this on production for a while now, it's worked well so far.